# Drawing a Rectangle in a Kivy GridLayout within a TabbedPanelItem

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm facing an issue with drawing a rectangle in a Kivy application within a GridLayout that is a child of a TabbedPanelItem. The problem is that the rectangle is not being drawn within the specified GridLayout but appears in the left-hand corner of the window.

Here's a simplified version of my Kivy code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<MyLayout>:
    viewport_layout: kv_viewport_layout

    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        size_hint: 0.60, 0.69
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.20, "y": 0.28}
        tab_width: 150

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "Viewport"
            font_size: 20
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                id: kv_viewport_layout
""")

class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    viewport_layout = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.viewport_layout.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5, mode="rgba")
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(0,0), size=(100,100))

        

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the `__init__()` method is telling kivy to draw the `Rectangle` at the lower left corner (at `(0,0)`) with a size of `(100,100)`, so that is what you see. Since you have not included any code to update the `Rectangle`, it just stays there. The easiest way to get a `Rectangle` that updates when the `GridLayout` update is to use `kv` to create it:

```
<MyLayout>:
    viewport_layout: kv_viewport_layout

    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        size_hint: 0.60, 0.69
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.20, "y": 0.28}
        tab_width: 150

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "Viewport"
            font_size: 20
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                id: kv_viewport_layout
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.5
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
```

The `kv` language will automatically create bindings to update the `pos` and `size` of the `Rectangle` when the `pos` and `size` of the `GridLayout` change. If you do it this way, you can remove the canvas instructions from the `__init__()` method.